# Cancel Animation in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'd like to stop a Three.js animation properly in order to execute a function afterwards.

This is the code I have :

```
var anim;

function animate() {
    anim = requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    checkRotation();

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    setTimeout(cancel, 10000);
}

function cancel() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(anim);
    finalCoords();
}

animate();
```

Being put like this, the animation `checkRotation()` indeed stops but the function `finalCoords()` keeps looping as if it was trapped in some kind of recursion.

I have also tried this :

```
var anim;

function animate(anima) {
    anima = requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    checkRotation();

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

function cancel(anima) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(anima);
    finalCoords();
}

animate(anim);

setTimeout(cancel(anim), 10000);
```

Now the loop stops but the function `finalCoords()` doesn't return proper results and the animation doesn't stop.

What did I do wrong ? and how can I fix it ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The problem in the first example is that in each animation frame you install another new timeout. Accordingly, for example, if you have 60 frames per second for 10,000 seconds you will set 600 million new timeouts.

2) The problem is the second example that you just are not transmitted in time-out function, but once it is called. Plus you are confused with the names of the variables in which to store the identifier of the frame of animation.

3) An improved version of the second example:

```
var stopAnimate = false;
function animate(time) {
    if (!stopAnimate) {
        checkRotation(time);
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    } else {
       finalCoords('final');
    }
}

animate();
setTimeout( function() {
  stopAnimate = true;
}, 1000);
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/02d37pxs/ ]